# clear cookies of com.android.browser

Tags: android, browser, adb

Is there a way to only clear only cookies of com.android.browser, via adb? When using `adb shell pm clear com.android.browser` it also clears out everything else.. I'm just interested in clearing the cookies via adb.

Comment: Only if you have root access. Then you can do something like `adb shell su -c "rm /data/data/com.android.browser/cache/whatever"`.